# How can I get the poll results using Facebook Graph-API v2.0?

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm interested to get the poll result from a question I had created on my Facebook profile.

Looking for a solution in the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/question

I read that the feature 'Question' is deprecated in the Graph-API v2.0, can I query for the poll result in other way?